# PKCS12 certificate password not accepted prompting in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, keychain

I have a *self-signed* ***PKCS12*** certificate file in the Download folder of my Android device (in *.pfx* format).

I use the following code to install it to the certification store:

```
 Intent intent = KeyChain.CreateInstallIntent();
 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath,password);
 intent.PutExtra(KeyChain.ExtraPkcs12, cert.RawData);
 StartActivity(intent);
```

I'm prompted for the password:

[image]

I always get the following error:

[image]

When I open the file in a file browser and click on it and use the ***exact same password***, I get the following screens:

[image]

[image]

What should I do differently when I open the installer prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the certificate data that has been provided for the `Intent` was corrupt.

So instead of the raw data:

`intent.PutExtra(KeyChain.ExtraPkcs12, cert.RawData);`

We have to use the `Export` method:

`intent.PutExtra(KeyChain.ExtraPkcs12, cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password));`